# Android Volley Request does not work using the Expandable List View and Base Expandable List Adapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-volley

Do not know why my volley request does not show any thing. It is not give me the failure instance but success listner does not call if I am using the ExpandableListView with BaseExpandableListAdapter.

See my Fragment class code: ShopCategoryFragment.java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.examples.testone.domain.CategorySection;
import com.examples.testone.domain.ShopCategory;
import com.examples.testone.domain.ShopCategoryParent;
import com.examples.testone.domain.ShopCategorySection;
import com.examples.testone.domain.response.ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse;
import com.examples.testone.network.volley.GsonRequest;

public class ShopCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

// private ShopCategorySectionListAdapter shopCategorySectionListAdapter;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private boolean requestRunning = false;
private String volleyRequestMode = "in";
final String _appLogTag = " - ShopCategoryFragment - ";

private List<ShopCategorySectionVO> shopCategorySectionVOs;
Map<ShopCategorySectionVO, List<ShopCategory>> myMapCollection;

private ExpandableListView expListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside onCreate");
    //this.requestQueue = SmartShopVolleySettings.getRequestQueue();
    this.requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    startRequest();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside onCreateView");
    View viewHierarchy = 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explist, container, false);
    // List View Settings
    expListView = 
(ExpandableListView)    viewHierarchy.findViewById(R.id.laptop_list);

    // getActivity(), this.shopCategorySectionVOs, this.collection );
    expListView.setAdapter
(new ShopCategoryExpandibleListAdapter(getActivity(), 
shopCategorySectionVOs,   myMapCollection));

    return viewHierarchy;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside onViewCreated");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside onDestroy");
    //this.requestQueue.cancelAll(this);
    //this.requestRunning = false;
    // cancelRequests();//Json shop lists
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside onPause");
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // inflater.inflate(R.menu.simplemap_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /*
     * switch (item.getItemId()) {
     * 
     * case R.id.simplemap_menu_info:
     * SimpleDialogFragment.createBuilder(this.getActivity(),
     * this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager())
     * .setMessage(Html.fromHtml
     * (getString(R.string.simplemap_info_details)))
     * .setTitle(R.string.simplemap_info_title) .show(); return true; }
     */
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void startRequest() {
Log.d(_appLogTag,"Inside on Start Request for getting the Shop Categories ");
    if ( !requestRunning ) {
        ShopCategoryFragment.this.requestRunning = true ;
String url = getString(R.string.shops_category_get_url, this.volleyRequestMode);
        Log.d(_appLogTag, "Url for json is:" + url);
GsonRequest<ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse> jsonObjectRequest = 
new GsonRequest<ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse>(Method.GET, 
url, ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse.class,
                null,
                getShopsCategoriesRequestSuccessListener(),
                getShopsCategoriesRequestErrorListener());
        jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
//Log.i(_appLogTag, "  volley request Finished: "+
jsonObjectRequest.getBodyContentType() + " More: " + jsonObjectRequest.toString());
        this.requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } else if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(_appLogTag, "  volley request is already running");
    }
/*myMapCollection = new LinkedHashMap<ShopCategorySectionVO, 
List<ShopCategory>>(); // My Map
shopCategorySectionVOs = new ArrayList<ShopCategorySectionVO>(); // My Section Headers
    List<ShopCategory> shopCategories = new ArrayList<ShopCategory>();

    ShopCategorySectionVO shopCategorySectionVO1 = 
new ShopCategorySectionVO("Dog", "icon", null);
    shopCategorySectionVOs.add(shopCategorySectionVO1);

    ShopCategory sc1 = new ShopCategory();      
    Title sc1t1 = new Title();
    sc1t1.setEn("Tommy");
    sc1.setTitle(sc1t1);

    Description sc1d1 = new Description();
    sc1d1.setEn("My Kuta Tommy");       
    sc1.setDescr(sc1d1);        
    shopCategories.add(sc1);

    ShopCategory sc2 = new ShopCategory();
    Title sc1t2 = new Title();
    sc1t2.setEn("Boomer");
    sc2.setTitle(sc1t2);

    Description sc1d2 = new Description();
    sc1d2.setEn("My Kuta Boomer");

    sc2.setDescr(sc1d2);
    shopCategories.add(sc2);

    myMapCollection.put(shopCategorySectionVO1, shopCategories);*/
}

private Response.Listener<ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse> 
getShopsCategoriesRequestSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ShopCategorySectionsRestResponse response) {

myMapCollection = new LinkedHashMap<ShopCategorySectionVO, List<ShopCategory>>(); 
    shopCategorySectionVOs = new ArrayList<ShopCategorySectionVO>();
    List<ShopCategory> shopCategories = new ArrayList<ShopCategory>();
            Log.d(_appLogTag,"Ready for going inside");
for (CategorySection categorySection :response.getShop_category_sections())   {
                Log.d(_appLogTag,"Inside Outer For");
ShopCategorySection catSection = categorySection.getShopCategorySection();
                ShopCategorySectionVO shopCategorySectionVO =
new ShopCategorySectionVO
 (catSection.getTitle(),catSection.getIcon(), 
 catSection.getBackcolor());
 shopCategorySectionVOs.add(shopCategorySectionVO);

 if (catSection.getShop_categories() != null && 
 catSection.getShop_categories().size() > 0) {
 Log.d(_appLogTag,"Inside Inner If");
for (ShopCategoryParent shopCategoryParent : catSection.getShop_categories()) {
        Log.d(_appLogTag,"Inside Inner For");
ShopCategory shopCategory = shopCategoryParent.getShopCategory();
                        shopCategories.add(shopCategory);
                    }// End of child For
}// End of IF
myMapCollection.put(shopCategorySectionVO, shopCategories); // Filling of Map
            }
            // End of Outer For
            requestRunning = false;
        }
    };
}

private Response.ErrorListener getShopsCategoriesRequestErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Log.d(_appLogTag,"Inside on create Shops Request Error Listener ");
            requestRunning = false;
        }
    };
}
}
```

and my BaseExpandableListAdapter.

```
 public class ShopCategoryExpandibleListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


final String _appLogTag = " - ShopCategoryExpandibleListAdapter - ";

// Define activity context
private Context mContext;

/*
 * Here we have a Hashmap containing a String key 
 * (can be Integer or other type but I was testing 
 * with contacts so I used contact name as the key)
*/ 
private Map<ShopCategorySectionVO, List<ShopCategory>> mListDataChild;

// ArrayList that is what each key in the above 
// hashmap points to
private List<ShopCategorySectionVO> mCategorySectionVOs;

// Hashmap for keeping track of our checkbox check states
private Map<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;

// Our getChildView & getGroupView use the viewholder patter
// Here are the viewholders defined, the inner classes are
// at the bottom
private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;

/*  
 *  For the purpose of this document, I'm only using a single
 *  textview in the group (parent) and child, but you're limited only
 *  by your XML view for each group item :)
*/ 
private String groupText;
private String childText;
//private String childText2;

/*  Here's the constructor we'll use to pass in our calling
 *  activity's context, group items, and child items
*/ 
public ShopCategoryExpandibleListAdapter(Context context,
List<ShopCategorySectionVO> listDataGroup, 
Map<ShopCategorySectionVO, List<ShopCategory>> listDataChild) {

    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside Constructor");

    mContext = context;
    mCategorySectionVOs = listDataGroup;
    mListDataChild = listDataChild;

    // Initialize our hashmap containing our check states here
    mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
}

@Override
public ShopCategory getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getChild");
List<ShopCategory> 
 listOfChilds = mListDataChild.get(mCategorySectionVOs.get(groupPosition));
 Log.d(_appLogTag, "So total number of childs in Group number "
 +groupPosition+" are "+listOfChilds.size());
//return mListDataChild.get(mCategorySectionVOs.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    return listOfChilds.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getChild ID");
     return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getChild View");
    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

    //  I passed a text string into an activity holding a getter/setter
    //  which I passed in through "ExpListChildItems".
    //  Here is where I call the getter to get that text
    //childText = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition).getChildText();
    ShopCategory shopCategory = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition);

    childText = shopCategory.getTitle().getEn();

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

   childViewHolder.mChildText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop_child);


        childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(R.layout.child_item, childViewHolder);

    } else {

        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView
                .getTag(R.layout.child_item);
    }

    childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);
    //childViewHolder.mChildText2.setText(childText2);
        /* 
     * You have to set the onCheckChangedListener to null
     * before restoring check states because each call to 
     * "setChecked" is accompanied by a call to the 
     * onCheckChangedListener
    */ 
    childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
        /*
         * if the hashmap mChildCheckStates<Integer, Boolean[]> contains
         * the value of the parent view (group) of this child (aka, the key),
         * then retrive the boolean array getChecked[]
        */
        boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);

        // set the check state of this position's checkbox based on the 
        // boolean value of getChecked[position]
        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

    } else {

        /*
        * if the hashmap mChildCheckStates<Integer, Boolean[]> does not
        * contain the value of the parent view (group) of this child (aka, the key),
        * (aka, the key), then initialize getChecked[] as a new boolean array
        *  and set it's size to the total number of children associated with 
        *  the parent group
        */
        boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];

 // add getChecked[] to the mChildCheckStates hashmap using mGroupPosition as the key
        mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

        // set the check state of this position's checkbox based on the 
        // boolean value of getChecked[position]
        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }

 childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {

                        boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                            getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

                    } else {
                     boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                            getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                    }
                }
            });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getChildrenCount");
//ShopCategory childList = mListDataChild.get(mCategorySectionVOs.get(groupPosition));
    return mListDataChild.get(mCategorySectionVOs.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getGroup");
    return mCategorySectionVOs.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getGroupCount");
    return mCategorySectionVOs.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getGroupId");
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  I passed a text string into an activity holding a getter/setter
    //  which I passed in through "ExpListGroupItems".
    //  Here is where I call the getter to get that text
    //groupText = getGroup(groupPosition).getGroupText();
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside getGroupView");
    groupText = ((ShopCategorySectionVO)getGroup(groupPosition)).getTitle();

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);

        // Initialize the GroupViewHolder defined at the bottom of this document
groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();

//groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);
groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop_head);

        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    } else {

        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(groupText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside hasStableIds");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    Log.d(_appLogTag, "Inside isChildSelectable");
    return false;
}


 public final class GroupViewHolder {

    TextView mGroupText;
 }

 public final class ChildViewHolder {

    TextView mChildText;
    TextView mChildText2;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
 }
 }
```

It does not make any sense If I just disable the adapter, volley request got get success and load data in my domain classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is that you want to fill ExpandableListView with data that are not loaded yet. In your onCreateView the myMapCollection is still empty. It is loaded after some time when the volley finishes its asyncTask. You need to refresh your UI when you get successful response that volley finished loading data.